# Blue/green deployment with micro services and DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-ecs, dns, bluegreen

Currently, we have on our test environment an *ECS Cluster* with micro services deployed. All micro services are talking to each other through *Route53* DNS CNAMEs like service1.company.com, service2.company.com, etc.

Here is a simplified schema of the infra:
[image: ECS Cluster for micro services]

The *ALB* listens on port 80 and everything works fine.

Now comes the troubles: I'm trying to build a blue/green deployment infra.

I basically know how to do it (*HAProxies*, 2x *ALBs*, 2x *ECS Clusters*). What I want to acheive can be seen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJOORneBTHI

I'm stuck with the fact that we are using CNAMEs for our micro services communications.

- So on the **blue** part:

CNAME service1.company.com -> ALBBlue

- On the **green** part:

CNAME service1.company.com -> ALBGreen

But that's something I cannot do of course.

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have 3 names when you're willing to do a blue/green deployment.

Two set of names, one for blue, one for green, which will works as is, and a production entrypoint which will point to either the blue name or green name.

The point of a blue/green deployment is to be able to test the full deploy before switching the clients entry point, so your services calls themselves don't have to use the entry point name itself.

Comment: But how to make the micro services point to each other in the same Cluster?
I cannot tell the micro services that they are on the blue/green by modifying their URL (service1.blue.company.com/service1.green.company.com)

Comment: Why can't you use blue/green names on each cluster ?

Comment: So it means the micro services must know in which "env" they are. That doesn't seem right to me. I must be missing something

Comment: That's just a variable you give to your services, as well as any credential, db location, whatever which is cluster dependent.

Comment: Ok so I would have blue.company.com, green.company.com and a third one?

Comment: Yes, your services should be able to take at least a dns suffix from an environment variable to build their own and others services urls.